# Issue with JPA native queries saying No property found for type

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring boot application using JPA native queries. These queries are located in a separate properties file. I have 3 queries called getSomething and getSomethingWithSomeParam and getSomethingWithOtherParam. When it was just getSomething, the endpoint worked fine. When I added getSomethingWithSomeParam endpoint/query, it also worked as expected.

However when I added getSomethingWithOtherParam, JPA started throwing this error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method ... DataAccessLayer.getSomethingWithOtherParam(...)! No Property getSomething found for type DTO!
```

This is what the data access layer looks like:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true)
public List<String> getSomething();

@Query(nativeQuery = true)
public List<String> getSomethingWithSomeParam(@Param("some") String some);

@Query(nativeQuery = true)
public List<String> getSomethingWithOtherParam(@Param("other") String other);
```

Does JPA not allow multiple queries with similar names if they have the same number and type of parameters? Why is JPA getting confused in which query to map each query method to?

Comment: Did you disable the getSomethingWithSomeParam() method and only try with the other two methods? Maybe it's pissed because your entity class doesn't have the 'other' field.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is not a problem because I have used this method many times.
Because methods are called statically from another layer, there is no problem defining methods and parameters in your code.
You may have set up server-side settings that cause errors. To do this, you can create a simple project to test this.